# Initializing a three dimensional array of arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a multidimentional array, as:

```
private static ArrayList [] [] pVTable = new ArrayList [35] [12];
```

My first try to initialize it was:

```
for (ArrayList[] x : pVTable) {
    for (ArrayList y : x) {
        y = new ArrayList<TableValue>();
    }
}
```

which didn't work.

I ended up doing it more manually, as in:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < pVTable.length; i++) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < pVTable[0].length; j++) {
        pVTable [i] [j] =  new ArrayList<TableValue>();
    }
}
```

which works fine.

Although I have a solution, I was wondering why the first (more elegant) piece of code doesn't do the same job?

Comment: that's because you are overwriting the object reference with a new ArrayList. Actually, y was anyways a null reference so initialization that ways would not have worked either ways. On a side note, [Arrays.fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill) may help you

Comment: I haven't seen .fill before, I'll try to remember that. If I read it correctly, though, it would assign the SAME reference to all the table entries, not create a new ArrayList for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet, if we strip away the syntactic sugar of the `foreach` operator (`:`), the code translates to:

```
for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < pVTable.length; xIndex++) {
    ArrayList[] x = pVTable[xIndex];
    for (int yIndex = 0; yIndex < x.length; yIndex++) {
        ArrayList y = x[yIndex];
        y = new ArrayList<TableValue>();
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing is ever assigned to the actual array – only to the temporary `y` variable.

Comment: When broken down this way, I can see what's going on. Thanks, Eli!

Answer (score 1):

In the first example your code although modifies *y* does **not** change *x*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I needed a little more explanation, as per Eli's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing ArrayList (part of collections api) with Arrays, which is rather confusing (for me anyway)

I would suggest something like this instead :

```
List<Point> myShape =  new ArrayList<Point>;
```

Where [point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) contains two ints representing X and Y.

Comment: Mmmhhh. Creating objects just to contain references to other objects sounds even more complicated to me, LOL. I guess I'm an old programmer still trying to program the old way!

Comment: @shakeshuck An arraylist is an object, as is TableValue. So you are doing this anyway.

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is that referencing row a, column b seems more straightforward than creating a new object to reference row a, column b. It feels like you're adding an extra element to do the same job? Like I said, maybe it's just an old brain's thinking...

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the first is incorrect. `y` is just a placeholder variable. Changing that doesn't change the underlying object, just the object that `y` refers to. You can see the same problem in the following code snippet:

```
public static  int x = 2;

public static void foo(int y) {
    y = 3;//does nothing outside of foo
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(x);//prints 2
    foo(x);
    System.out.println(x);//prints 2, x hasn't changed.
}
```